# NullObject pattern with type-graphql

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I have a typescript question when dealing with inheritance and a NullObject pattern.

Consider the following:

```js
@ObjectType({ implements: Segment })
export class NullSegment extends Segment {
  public static readonly NAME = 'Other'

  @Field(() => Trait)
  @ManyToOne(() => Trait)
  trait: Trait

  static build(input: NullSegmentInput): NullSegment {
    const out = new this()
    out.name = this.NAME
    out.trait = input.trait
    return out
  }
}

export type NullableSegment<T extends Segment> = T | NullSegment
```

there are many other implementations of Segment.

elsewhere we have:

```js
@ObjectType({ implements: Trait })
export class HealthScoreTrait extends Trait {
  @Field(() => [NullableSegment<HealthscoreSegment>], { nullable: true })
  @OneToMany(() => Segment, (segment) => segment.trait, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    cascade: true,
    nullable: true
  })
  healthscoreSegments: NullableSegment<HealthscoreSegment>[]
}
```

When this resolves to the graph I would like the available types be HealthScoreSegment | NullSegment.

but when I do the following I get an type error with @Field()

like so [image]

Does someone know of a workable pattern here.  Do I need to make UnionTypes couplets for each Segment.  That seems really unDRY

Comment: Have you tried using generic types (classes)? 
https://typegraphql.com/docs/generic-types.html

Comment: Noooo, i did know about that pattern.  I'll give that a shot -- that looks like the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best answer ... but this works:

```js
const NullableHealthscoreSegment = createUnionType({
  name: "NullableHealthscoreSegment", // the name of the GraphQL union
  types: () => [HealthscoreSegment, NullSegment] as const, // function that returns tuple of object types classes
});

@ObjectType({ implements: Trait })
@ChildEntity()
export class HealthScoreTrait extends Trait {
  @Field(() => [NullableHealthscoreSegment], { nullable: true })
  @OneToMany(() => Segment, (segment) => segment.trait, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    cascade: true,
    nullable: true,
    lazy: true,
  })
  healthscoreSegments: Lazy<NullableSegment<HealthscoreSegment>[]>
}
```

Comment: Asked on Type-Graphql's Gitter but I'll ask here too. How are you using this on the client, if I may ask? Or rather, what do you do differently, than when just null had been available?

Comment: I just it for persisted dynamic filtering.  i.e find all customers that have do not have a healthscore segment for example